# Random variables and integrals

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, expectation, almost-everywhere

[image]

Could someone please explain how this holds:

$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} f d\mu = \int_{\Omega}f(Y_n)d\mathbb{P}$

Does it use the following proposition?

[image]

Furthermore how does $\mathbb{E}(f(X_n)) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(f(X))$ hold? It is not clear to me how proposition 3.4 is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step
$$\int_{\mathbb R}f ~d\mu_n=\int_{\Omega}f(Y_n)~d\mathbb P$$
in Theorem 3.9 is indeed a consequence of Proposition 3.4.

Consider the measure spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ and $(\mathbb R,\mathscr B(\mathbb R),\mu_n)$ (where $\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra).
Since $Y_n$ is a random variable on the probability space $\Omega$,
it is by definition a measurable map from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$.
Furthermore,
we notice that for every measurable set $A\subset\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$,
we have that
$$\mu_n(A)=\mathbb P[Y_n\in A]=\mathbb P(Y_n^{-1}(A))=(\mathbb P\circ Y_n^{-1})(A),$$
hence $\mu_n=\mathbb P\circ Y_n^{-1}$.
Consequently,
by applying Proposition 3.4 directly,
we obtain that for any measurable function $f$,
we have that
$$\int_{\mathbb R}f~d\mu_n=\int_{\Omega}f\circ Y_n~d\mathbb P.$$
Given that every continuous function is measurable,
this gives you the equality you wanted.

As for $\mathbb E(f(X_n))\to\mathbb E(f(X))$,
as mentioned in the statement of Theorem 3.9,
this is a direct consequence of Proposition 3.4.
Indeed,
if we generalize the steps we did in the previous paragraph to an arbitrary random variable $X$ with distribution $\mu$,
then for any measurable function $f$,
we know that
$$\mathbb E(f(X))=\int_{\Omega}f(X)~d\mathbb P$$
by definition of the expected value of the random variable $f(X)$ (indeed,
a composition of measurable maps is measurable, so $f(X)$ is a random variable),
and thus
$$\mathbb E(f(X))=\int_{\Omega}f(X)~d\mathbb P=\int_{\mathbb R}f~d\mu.$$
Therefore,
saying that $\mu_n\Rightarrow\mu$ is really exactly the same as saying that $\mathbb E(f(X_n))\to\mathbb E(f(X))$ for every $f$ continuous and bounded,
where $X_n\sim\mu_n$ and $X\sim\mu$.